# Authentication into Google BigQuery without using Environment Variables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-colaboratory

I'm making a simple script in Google Colabs (Jupyter Notebook) that can grab stuff from our big data environment (in BigQuery) and analyze it. I'm avoiding using environmental variables as most of the engineers won't know how to set it up. Ideally, i'm looking for a way to authenticate in using our Google username/password. Does anyone have any experience authenticating into GBQ this way? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Colab docs contain an example showing [how to issue an authenticated BigQuery query](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/bigquery.ipynb).

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
print('Authenticated')
```

Then,

```
# Display query output immediately

%%bigquery --project yourprojectid
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as total_rows
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.gsod`
```